# Балансировка дерева и приведение его к АВЛ сбалансированному дереву

Tags: c++, дерево

В файле записаны числа, нужно их считать, построить дерево поиска. После этого сбалансировать дерево, выполнив RR поворот. Проблема возникла с тем, как определить именно несбалансированный узел (есть гарантия, что такой узел только один). Написал функцию, которая определяет высоту заданного ей узла. А как найти именно несбалансированный узел? Ниже функция, которая возвращает высоту узла.

```
 int HeightNode(PNode Tree)
 {
     int l,r,height = 0;
     if(Tree != 0)
    {
         l = HeightNode(Tree -> Left);
         r = HeightNode(Tree -> Right);
         height = ((l > r) ? l : r) + 1;
    }
    return height;
 }
```

Comment: Просто воспользоваться определением АВЛ дерева нельзя? (То, что высота левого и правого поддеревьев отличается больше чем на 1) Например, при добавлении узла в сбалансированное дерево, если нужно сделать LL или RR поворот, то разность высот равна двум.

Comment: @Imieee, дело в том, что в структуре дерева не указана разность между правым деревом и левым, так как в задании сказано, не использовать подобное поле для описания элемента дерева.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение получилось таким. Вроде работает.

```
 void FindDebalancedNode(PNode & tree)
 {
    if (!tree)
        return;
    FindDebalancedNode(tree->Left);
    FindDebalancedNode(tree->Right);
    int leftSubtree = HeightOfSubtree(tree -> Left);
    int rightSubtree = HeightOfSubtree(tree -> Right);
    if (leftSubtree + 1 < rightSubtree)
    {
        DoRRTurn(tree); 
    }
}

 int HeightOfSubtree(PNode tree)
 {
     int l,r,height = 0;
     if(tree != 0)
     {
         l = HeightOfSubtree(tree -> Left);
         r = HeightOfSubtree(tree -> Right);
         height = ((l > r) ? l : r) + 1;
     }
     return height;
  }

 void DoRRTurn(PNode & p)
 {
    PNode q = p-> Right;
    p->Right = q -> Left;
    q->Left = p;
    p = q;
 }
```

Comment: Поставьте уже зеленую галочку на ответе.